# adjective + "issue of whether"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

According to Garner's fourth edition,

> ***Question whether***; *✳question of whether; ✳question as to whether*. The
> first has a long literary lineage: it properly uses the noun clause
> beginning with whether in apposition to question. The other two are
> minor prolixities.
>
> Although ***issue whether*** is typically better, *issue of whether* has
> certain justifiable uses in which **of** is obligatory, usually when
> *issue* is modified by an adjective.

What are those *justifiable uses*?

Secondly, why does an adjective make **of** obligatory?

Comment: [Garner's](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA961&lpg=PA961&dq=Although+issue+whether+is+typically+better,+issue+of+whether+has+certain+justifiable+uses+in+which+of+is+obligatory,+usually+when+issue+is+modified+by+an+adjective.&source=bl&ots=7x0d4VjJUl&sig=ACfU3U0tJyQ1eKtOZM0qrkiGFt4z7jLFEA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Although%20issue%20whether%20is%20typically%20better%2C%20issue%20of%20whether%20has%20certain%20justifiable%20uses%20in%20which%20of%20is%20obligatory%2C%20usually%20when%20issue%20is%20modified%20by%20an%20adjective.&f=false) gives examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth > _**Question whether**; ✳question of whether; ✳question as to whether_. The first has a long literary lineage: it properly uses the noun clause  beginning with whether in apposition to question. The other two are minor prolixities.

Comment: I repeat. Garner's gives actual examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I cannot infer from them a general rule

Comment: But surelu they're relevant data.